# Converting HTML table to JS object

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table

I have a table that looks like this which I'm using JS to convert to a JS object:

```
|column-1|column-2|column-3|column-4|column-5|
|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|My Name |  Date  |Message |John Doe|Phone #s|
                           |Jhn Doe2|Phone #s|
                           |Jhn Doe3|Phone #s|
                           |Jhn Doe4|Phone #s|
                           |Jhn Doe5|Phone #s|
```

This is my JS code:

```
var table = document.getElementById('table');
  var jsonArr = [];
  for(var i =0,row;row = table.rows[i];i++){
       var colmn = row.cells;

         var recipeints = [{
          "phone_number": colmn[4].innerHTML,
          "recipient_name": colmn[3].innerHTML
         }];
         var message = {
            "message_by": colmn[0].innerHTML,
            "message_date": new Date(),
            "message_recipients": recipeints,
            "message_text": colmn[2].innerHTML
        };
        console.log(message);
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that the console message outputs 5 different object arrays with the `message` data but I'd like only one object output with nested objects for columns 4 and 5.

This is an instance of the output:

```
{message_by: "My name", message_date: Mon Dec 18 2017 14:32:29, message_recipients: Array(1), message_text: "Message"}
{message_by: "", message_date: Mon Dec 18 2017 14:32:29, message_recipients: Array(1), message_text: ""}
{message_by: "", message_date: Mon Dec 18 2017 14:32:29, message_recipients: Array(1), message_text: ""}
{message_by: "", message_date: Mon Dec 18 2017 14:32:29, message_recipients: Array(1), message_text: ""}
{message_by: "", message_date: Mon Dec 18 2017 14:32:29, message_recipients: Array(1), message_text: ""}
```

And this is the output I'm aiming for:

```
{message_by: "My Name", message_date: Mon Dec 18 2017 14:32:29, message_recipients: Array(5), message_text: "test"}
message_by:"My Name"
message_date:Mon Dec 18 2017 14:32:29 {}
message_recipients:Array(5)
    0:{phone_number: "0700100100", recipient_name: "John Doe"}
    1:{phone_number: "0700100200", recipient_name: "John Doe 2"}
    2:{phone_number: "0700100300", recipient_name: "John Doe 3"}
    3:{phone_number: "0700100400", recipient_name: "John Doe 4"}
    4:{phone_number: "0700100500", recipient_name: "John Doe 5"}
message_text:"sample"
```

That is, I'd like output only one object and merge the columns 4 and 5 to avoid null fields in multiple objects. How can I achieve this?

**More Info**

The code of the dynamically generated table is as shown:

```
<table id='table'>
   <tr>
      <td align='left' width='200'>My Name</td>
      <td align='left' width='200'>2017-12-18 15:07:33</td>
      <td align='left' width='200'>Sample Text</td>
      <td align='left' width='200'>0700100100</td>
      <td align='left' width='200'>John Doe</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td align='left' width='200'></td>
      <td align='left' width='200'></td>
      <td align='left' width='200'></td>
      <td align='left' width='200'>0700100200</td>
      <td align='left' width='200'>John Doe 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td align='left' width='200'></td>
      <td align='left' width='200'></td>
      <td align='left' width='200'></td>
      <td align='left' width='200'>0700100300</td>
      <td align='left' width='200'>John Doe 3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td align='left' width='200'></td>
      <td align='left' width='200'></td>
      <td align='left' width='200'></td>
      <td align='left' width='200'>0700100400</td>
      <td align='left' width='200'>John Doe 4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td align='left' width='200'></td>
      <td align='left' width='200'></td>
      <td align='left' width='200'></td>
      <td align='left' width='200'>0700100500</td>
      <td align='left' width='200'>John Doe 5</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Limit the for loop to columns 4 and 5? I honestly can't tell where the issue is. The answer is "rewrite your code to do what you want instead"

Comment: The different methods I've tried loop through the entire table including the null fields, that's why I'm here

Comment: Can you add example table HTML to your question?

Comment: I just edited the question. I've added an example HTML table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used mostly your own code but pulled the first row out of the loop.

```js
var table = document.getElementById('table');

var colmn = table.rows[0].cells;

var message = {
  "message_by": colmn[0].innerHTML,
  "message_date": new Date(),
  "message_recipients": [],
  "message_text": colmn[2].innerHTML
};

for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
  colmn = row.cells;

  message.message_recipients.push({
    "phone_number": colmn[4].innerHTML,
    "recipient_name": colmn[3].innerHTML
  });
}
console.log(message);
```

```css
td {
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<table id='table'>
  <tr>
    <td>My Name</td>
    <td>2017-12-18 15:07:33</td>
    <td>Sample Text</td>
    <td>0700100100</td>
    <td>John Doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>0700100200</td>
    <td>John Doe 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>0700100300</td>
    <td>John Doe 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>0700100400</td>
    <td>John Doe 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>0700100500</td>
    <td>John Doe 5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne. You just saved my afternoon

Answer (score 0):

You can keep one object and work with it and some conditions, and only push it to the jsonArr when necessary.

```
var table = document.getElementById('table');
var jsonArr = [];
var object;
for(var i =0,row;row = table.rows[i];i++){
     var colmn = row.cells;

  if(colmn[0].innerHTML != ''){
    if(object !== undefined){
      jsonArr.push(object);
    }
    object = {
      message_by : colmn[0].innerHTML,
      message_date : new Date(),
      message_text : colmn[2].innerHTML,
      message_recipients : [],
    }
  }
        var recipient = {
    "phone_number": colmn[4].innerHTML,
    "recipient_name": colmn[3].innerHTML
   };
   object.message_recipients.push(recipient);
}
jsonArr.push(object);
console.log(jsonArr);
```

If your column-1, in the 2nd row, print "My name" too, you can use `colmn[0].innerHTML != object.message_by` to check if you need to push the object and start to build another.

Comment: Fixed, I'm sorry. Forgot about the last push. :(